# 0x00 hex over TCP socket in QT

Tags: qt, tcp, hex, arrays

I have problem with sending 0x00 over tcp.
Data like 0x01 are ok, server receiving as 00000001, but when is 0x00 - no receive message on serwer.

Client code:

```
QByteArray sender="\x00";
socket.write(sender);
```

Server code:

```
    QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();
    QString str = QString(Data.toHex());
    qDebug()<<str;

    //disp bytes
    char myByte = Data.at(0);

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i) 
    {
        qDebug() << ((myByte >> i) & 1);
    }
```

How can i send 0x00 hex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constructing a `QByteArray` from a string, but strings are terminated by the character 0. So your array is empty.

Use a [different constructor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#QByteArray-3), i.e.

```
const QByteArray sender(1, '\0');
```